# Creating buttons on a form that should go according to data retrieved from a database using linq to sql

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I'm new to programming (I'm still studying), and I'm trying to write a program for a retail fruit and vegetable store.

On one page I'm trying to create buttons for all the products according to the data from the database I created in SQL Server. I'm using Linq-to-SQL to connect to the database.

The problem is that I'm trying to set the text on the buttons that every button should display the name of another product, but it just doesn't work out (the owner of the store can also add products so I wrote a method to create the buttons accordingly). Can anyone help me figure that out?

This is my code:

```
private void ChezkysFruits_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    db = new DataClasses1DataContext();

    for(int i=0,y=0;i<=db.Items.Count();i++,y++)
    {
         Button button = new Button();

         if (i == 5)
             y = 0;

         int xPoint = (i < 5 ? 800 : 890);
         int yPoint = 50 * y + 100;

         button.Location = new Point(xPoint, yPoint);

         button.Click += new EventHandler(ButtonClickEvent);
         button.Tag = i + 1;
         button.Size = new Size(75,50);
         button.BackColor = Color.Aqua;

         this.Controls.Add(button);

        //this line of code is underlined red and it does not allow me to do it...
        button.Text = db.Items.names[i].ToString(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the message when you hover your mouse over the red squiggly?

Comment: 'System.data.Linq.Table<FruitStore1.Item>' does not contain a definition for names....

Comment: can you show what your `DataClasses1DataContext` looks like ..? how come you don't create the winforms to show / display the actual contents / structure of the items that you are retrieving from the database..?

Comment: You want to index into `Items` since currently you are asking for the `names` property on the entire collection. I don't know if items have a collection of names or if you just misplaced the indexer, but do : `Items[i]`.names....`

Comment: public partial class Item : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
 {
  
  private static PropertyChangingEventArgs emptyChangingEventArgs = new PropertyChangingEventArgs(String.Empty);
  
  private int _itemID;
  
  private int _supplierID;
  
  private int _categoryID;
  
  private int _ItemType;
  
  private string _name;
  
  private string _available;

Answer (score 0):

`db.Items` can be seen as just a list of items. You could, for example, loop through it and display the name of each item like so:

```
foreach(var item in db.Items)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
}
```

So within the loop you always deal with one item from the list.

Likewise, within the `for` loop you should always deal with one item, for example by changing it to:

```
var items = db.Items.ToArray();
for(int i=0,y=0;i <= items.Length;i++,y++)
{
    ...
    var item = items[i];
    button.Text = item.Name;
}
```

you can make this more efficient by only getting the names from the database:

```
var itemNames = db.Items.Select(i => i.Name).ToArray();
for(int i=0,y=0;i <= itemNames.Length;i++,y++)
{
    ...
    var name = itemNames[i];
    button.Text = itemName;
}
```